# Two sets and functions that satisfy the following conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to come up with two sets and functions called **A**, **B** that satisfy three conditions. The two functions are **f: A ⇒ B** and **g: B ⇒ A**. The three conditions are:

(i) Both functions must be onto.

(ii) **f(g(x)) = x** for all **x** in B

(iii) There exists **y** in A such that **g(f(y)) ≠ y**.

I'm thinking that the two sets should be the set of all positive integers and that only one of the functions should be one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't happen. Let $y\in A$. Since $g$ is onto, we can find $x\in B$ such that $g(x)=y$. Since $f$ is onto we can write $x=f(z)$ for some $z\in A$. Then
$$g(f(z))=g(x)=y$$
so that
$$f(g(f(z))=f(y)$$
while according to (ii):
$$f(g(f(z))=f(z)=x$$
This shows that $x=f(y)$ so that $g(f(y))=g(x)=y$.